# How to get Emacs buffer-menu always to show mode-names?

Tags: emacs

When doing a Ctrl+left mouse button in a buffer, I get the Emacs buffer-menu. When lots of buffers are open, Emacs will arrange them according to buffer mode. I.e. I will have a sub-menu for C++, for Java, etc. If too few buffers are open, this is not the case. Can I tweak this behaviour to always get the subcategories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should customize the value of `mouse-buffer-menu-mode-mult`, for example putting something like this in your init file (`.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el`):

```
(setq mouse-buffer-menu-mode-mult 0)
```

---

From the documentation:

> mouse-buffer-menu-mode-mult is a variable defined in `mouse.el'.
> Its value is 4
>
> **Documentation:**
>
> Group the buffers by the major mode groups on <C-down-mouse-1>?
> This number which determines (in a hairy way) whether <C-down-mouse-1>
> will split the buffer menu by the major modes (see
> `mouse-buffer-menu-mode-groups') or just by menu length.
> Set to 1 (or even 0!) if you want to group by major mode always, and to
> a large number if you prefer a mixed multitude.  The default is 4.
>
> You can customize this variable.
>
> This variable was introduced, or its default value was changed, in
> version 20.3 of Emacs.

Comment: Worked perfectly. It is even customizable -- although it is under the `Mouse` category, not `Buffer menu`, as I expected.